TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len(), then i pass list to func
I wanted to write a recursive function that calculates the sum of the elements in an array, but when I pass the array to the function, it thinks that I passed an integer and writes that there is no len() function for it
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

def rec_sum(arr):
    if len(arr) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return(arr[len(arr) - 1] + rec_sum(arr.pop(len(arr) - 1)))

print(rec_sum(arr1))


Please update your question with the full error traceback. This should show you where the error occurs.

@quamrana it's plainly clear from the code, no? If len(arr) received an int, then it was passed an int. There are two calls. We can see rec_sum(arr1) doesn't pass in an int. We can see the other call passes in an int. Am I missing something?

arr.pop returns the value being removed, not the resulting shorter list.

@VLAZ: Its plain to you and to me, but apparently not to the OP. Which is quite understandable since recursion is hard.

Don't use recursion when a simple loop will suffice. It's far less efficient, and will (eventually) raise an exception if the list is too long.

@quamrana right, but why does the question need the useless information? It's useless to us. It's been useless to OP. Pretty much useless for future visitors, too.  Honestly, this is just yet another thing that just should have been debugged and doesn't really help build up a robust library of common Q&A.

@VLAZ: It may not be useless to all the future programmers that come here. Its pointless making all of them run the code themselves to produce the same output when it could be right there in front of them.

@chepner but...you don't even need a loop? sum(arr) But I suspect this is an exercise. Creating a recursive sum (and other simple loopable problems) is the usual way to teach recursion. Lets people focus on the recursion part, not on finding out what the algorithm would be.

@VLAZ The advice to avoid linear recursion like this applies to all functions, whether or not built-in equivalents already exist. (And there are other ways to learn recursion aside from treating lists as recursive data structures.)

Python's list.pop() method returns the element that is popped, so you are passing an integer to the recursive function call and not another list. Try using list slicing:
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

def rec_sum(arr):
    if len(arr) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return(arr[len(arr) - 1] + rec_sum(arr[:len(arr)-1]))

print(rec_sum(arr1))

Output:
21


And if you want to use pop, do something like return arr.pop() + rec_sum(arr). Python guarantees left-to-right evaluation of +'s operands, so you know the array will be modified before rec_sum is called.

спасибо, теперь все работает

@chepner Sure, I agree, but I'm not here to completely rewrite code -- it is often easier for people to understand answers when their code is made to work with minimal changes.
